# Turkish characters HTML encode error at Mandrill API

Tags: c#, json, mandrill, html-encode

I am using .net 4.5.2 c# wpf application and mandrill email serving api

Their api results so bad and need to manually fix character errors

So far I did these 2 things but still errors happens that drives me nuts

```
string srLoginCity = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(myPerEmail.srLoginCity);
string srRegisterCity = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(myPerEmail.srRegisterCity);

srLoginCity = RemoveDiacritics(srLoginCity);
srRegisterCity = RemoveDiacritics(srRegisterCity);
```

Even though both `HtmlEncode` and `RemoveDiacritics` latest error happened like below

The city name was : `Diyarbakır`

Their api thrown 500 internal server error with no description

`Diyarbakır` is still result as `Diyarbakır` after both process

So what else I need to do in order to convert it correctly so mandrill api which takes json data will not fail ?

I believe I either need to convert `ı` letter to `i` or encode it somehow.

There can be other letters which would fail so I don't want manual `ı` to `i` solution.

Comment: If you're trying to convert non-ascii Unicode characters to their "most similar" ASCII equivalent, that's not so easy.  See maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624646/convert-unicode-char-to-closest-most-similar-char-in-ascii-net or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403877/find-similar-ascii-character-in-unicode.

Comment: Or, to escape non-ASCII characters, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615559/converting-unicode-strings-to-escaped-ascii-string

Comment: @dbc ty for answer yes i can escape them but if browser renders them as escaped that would not work for me i suppose :D

Comment: @dbc  yep i just tried browser does not render properly. it is